# On load page CSS image transform scale smoothly (change image size on page load)

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions, scale, transition

This is my [link](http://hashtaginc.us/Projects/Relax/index_plus.html).
When I click on and icon it gets bigger then other for prompting on which page you're.
I need it to transform scale smoothly (icon become bigger smoothly).

Comment: please post the relevant parts of your code here that you have tried to accomplish this.

Comment: I'd done this for changing the icon size of active page
<a href="positive_thinking.html"><img src="image/bubble_plus1.png" width="150" /></a>
and rest links are with original width,
on every page i just add width size of icon accordingly

Comment: I am saying post your code here, StackOverflow is for posting problems with code you have, questions are supposed to contain the code needing help with

Comment: <td><a href="positive_thinking.html"><img src="image/bubble_plus1.png" width="150" /></a></td>

as i need active link prominent, i increase icon size on each page resectively

Comment: As Patrick said, you need to post your attempted and from there we can assist you. One thing I'll say from viewing your html is that you should change the table into divides with `display: inline-block;`, so that they can rearrange/stack on a smaller (mobile) screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this using simple technique used in css, leave the width of icon the it is on corresponding page and just add the id.

```
<td id="zoom"><a href="visualization.html"><img src="image/bubble_plus3.png" width="150" /></a></td>
```

And the css:

```
#zoom img {
/*transform:scale 1s;
animation: scale 1s;*/
-moz-animation: scale 0.5s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: scale 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: scale 0.5s; /* Opera */
margin-top:-20px;}
@keyframes scale {
from {
    width:107px;
}
to {
    width:150px;
}}
@-moz-keyframes scale { /* Firefox */
from {
    width:107px;
}
to {
    width:150px;
}}
@-webkit-keyframes scale { /* Safari and Chrome */
from {
    width:107px;
}
to {
    width:150px;
}}
@-o-keyframes scale { /* Opera */
from {
    width:107px;
}
to {
    width:150px;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#itemdisplay{
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    background: #ff0;
}
#itemdisplay:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This CSS code will do what you want:

```
.zoom {
    -webkit-transition:all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition:all 1s linear;
    -o-transition:all 1s linear;
    transition:all 1s linear;
}

.zoom:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
    -o-transform:scale(1.5);
    transform:scale(1.5);
}
```